# mysql.connector imports through the python shell, but still throws error in python module

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a simple python module `test.py`. Its content is:

```
import mysql.connector
```

When I run it (using `pyCharm`), it gives this error:

```
    C:\xxx\Software\Website\django\Scripts\python.exe
    C:\xxx\Software\Website\django\MyDB\test.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\xxx\Software\Website\django\MyDB\test.py", line 1, in <module>
                import mysql.connector ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
            
Process finished with exit code 1
```

So it can't find `mysql.connector`. But when I go into the `python shell` (launched from the directory of `test.py`), running `>>> import mysql.connector` doesn't give any error. So the `mysql.connector` package must be installed.

How come running the python module gives an error, while running the same python instruction through the python shell doesn't? How can the first be fixed?

Comment: Are you using the same python installation (try `python3 test.py` and `python3 -c 'import mysql.connector'`)? Are you in the same environment (or venv)?

Comment: @DanielB `python test.py` works as well. It only gives the error when I run it using pyCharm (you know, pressing the green "play" button). Is it a pyCharm problem then?

Comment: it's likely using a different python installation or environment, then. Check the values of `sys.executable` and `sys.path`. Otherwise, check the docs for [using packages with pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#packages-tool-window).